# When will caption support be added to the YouTube Data API V3

Tags: api, youtube, captions

When will caption support be added to the YouTube Data API V3? In the meantime, what option do I have to download it (python) for an arbitrary public video (not one I own)?

Answer (score 1):

Caption support was added to YouTube API v3, according to [this document](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions).

Suggested way to get all captions of a video is to use a HTTP request:

```
GET video.google.com/timedtext?lang={LANG}&v={VIDEOID}
```

For example:

```
http://video.google.com/timedtext?lang=en&v=sOEAD-gfJ_M
```

No need to login.